# Diffraction pattern from laser shone on coffe-filter plastered on glass pane

Tags: visible-light, laser, interference, diffraction

I make an ordinary coffe filter wet and plaster it on a glass pane.  I then shine a laser onto the filter (on the side of the pane with the coffe filter).  When I do this, I see what I assume is an interference pattern, kind of like airy-discs, on the other side of the pane.

I can't figure out what is actually happens here.  Is it actually an interference pattern that I see?  If it is, I have the feeling that I might be able to ascertain the thickness of the glass pane from the details of the interference pattern.  Is that possible?

I am a physics teacher (high school level), and if I have an explanation of what is going on here, I think it could be a neat little experiment, requiring nothing special in the way of equipment.

Comment: Do you think you could add a picture of what you did - it would help a great deal.

Comment: I am on holiday, away from everything right now, but will add a picture as soon as the easter holiday is over.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If it looks similar to this then I would say yes its an interference pattern. Are you getting the image on the back surface of the glass or projected onto a surface beyond the glass?
By the way if you want to try an easy way of getting a diffraction pattern hold you fingers very close together without touching. Then hold them close to your eye in front of the screen your looking at right now. You will see four to six dark parallel lines.

Comment: It does look similar, except the center is a maximum, surrounded by a dark ring, then around that another max-ring, and so on.  Very much like an airy-pattern.

Comment: Sounds like you do have a diffraction pattern. Try it on different thicknesses of glass and you may see the maximums  and minimums alternate. You can try similar experiments by poking tiny holes in miscellaneous materials and shinning a laser through and onto a wall.